# Reset cursor of jmappane

Tags: java, swing, geotools

There is the standard zoom tool on the left where you can click and the cursor on the mappane changes to the same icon as the tool.
I have implemented two other zoom buttons which should reset the cursor icon to the default icon. 
Where can I find the method or the class which can handle this?
(By reset I actually meant it should deactivate the clicked tool again)

I extended the ZoomOutAction and ZoomInAction classes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extending `ZoomInAction` or `ZoomOutAction` you need to extend from `NoToolAction`. That's it.